# Replace for-switch loop with a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Message object which wraps a message format I do not have control over. The format is a simple list of Key/Value pairs. I want to extract a list of Users from a given Message. For example given the following message...

```
1. 200->....
2. 300->....
3. ....
4. 405->.... 
5. 001->first_user_name
6. 002->first_user_phone
7. 003->first_user_fax
8. 001->second_user_name
9. 001->third_user_name
10. 002->third_user_phone
11. 003->third_user_fax
12. 004->third_user_address
13. .....
14. 001->last_user_name
15. 003->last_user_fax
```

I want to extract four Users with the provided properties set. The initial keys 200/300....405 represent fields I don't need and can skip to get to the User data.

Each users data is in consecutive fields but the number of fields varies depending on how much information is known about a user. The following method does what I'm looking for. It uses an enumeration of possible key types and a method to find the index of the first field with user data.

```
private List<User> ParseUsers( Message message )
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>( );
    User user = null; String val = String.Empty;

    for( Int32 i = message.IndexOfFirst( Keys.Name ); i < message.Count; i++ ) 
    {
        val = message[ i ].Val;

        switch( message[ i ].Key )
        {
            case Keys.Name:
                user = new User( val );
                users.Add( user ); 
                break;
            case Keys.Phone:
                user.Phone = val;
                break;
            case Keys.Fax:
                user.Fax = val;
                break;
            case Keys.Address:
                user.Address = val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

I'm wondering if its possible to replace the method with a Linq query. I'm having trouble telling Linq to select a new user and populate its fields with all matching data until you find the start of the next user entry.

Note: Relative key numbers are random (not 1,2,3,4) in the real message format.

Comment: are you using Resharper? it's pretty good at refactoring loops to LINQ expressions.

Comment: What would be the benefit of turning this into a LINQ query? Your code looks good to me as it is.

Comment: @marian.. thanks for the suggestion, I have not used Resharper but I will take a look

Comment: @dtb .. thanks.. the code works as is for sure but every time I pass through the file its in I have this annoying feeling that it could be replaced it with a couple of lines of Linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the benefit in changing your code to a LINQ query, but it's definitely possible:

```
private List<User> ParseUsers(Message message)
{
    return Enumerable
        .Range(0, message.Count)
        .Select(i => message[i])
        .SkipWhile(x => x.Key != Keys.Name)
        .GroupAdjacent((g, x) => x.Key != Keys.Name)
        .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Val))
        .Select(d => new User(d[Keys.Name])
        {
            Phone   = d.ContainsKey(Keys.Phone)   ? d[Keys.Phone]   : null,
            Fax     = d.ContainsKey(Keys.Fax)     ? d[Keys.Fax]     : null,
            Address = d.ContainsKey(Keys.Address) ? d[Keys.Address] : null,
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

using

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g, x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: +1: answers OP's question and is *quite convincing* at telling him to leave his fine code as it is.

Comment: @dtb.. yup edited version works a treat.. haha.. not entirely sure I understand exactly how just yet but thanks again.. its great to see there's always a way to do something.. and I'm learning more about Linq by going through your code

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting message into a `List<List<KeyValuePait<int, string>>>` where each `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` represents a single user. You could then do something like:

```
// SplitToUserLists would need a sensible implementation.
List<List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>> splitMessage = message.SplitToUserLists();
IEnumerable<User> users = splitMessage.Select(ConstructUser);
```

With

```
private User ConstructUser(List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> userList)
{
     return userList.Aggregate(new User(), (user, keyValuePair) => user[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePair.Val);
}
```

Comment: @joey.. hi Joey.. thanks for your post.. been fiddling with dtb's code .. which works a treat now (thanks dtb).. I'd have to reimplement my User class to work with ConstructUser as is and Id be reading through the message more than once this way.. but it's interesting to see the different approaches! thanks again

Comment: No problem. I think the best solution is still the one you started with. Though perhaps try to refactor the switch into User or some UserBuilder object.

Comment: +1 .. yup thats a good suggestion.. pass it an enumerable of fields split as u suggested/via GroupAdjacent or similar and let it take care of its own creation, User format is unlikely to change (Ahem!) ... so I think I'd go with User rather than UserFactory/UserBuilder but even so putting the creation code in the User would be nicer than having it inside the switch at another location. Thanks Joey.

Answer (score 1):

No, and the reason being, in general, most LINQ functions, in the same way as SQL queries, deal with unordered data, i.e. they don't make assumptions about the order of the incoming data. That gives them flexibility to be parallelized, etc. Your data has intrinsic order, so doesn't fit the model of querying.

Comment: @tim.. yup I was thinking that when I wrote the loop but every time I skipped through it I had this niggling feeling that it was possible..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any performance benefit, but it increases readability a lot in my opinion.

A possible solution could look like this:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")
           .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {"->"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .GroupByOrder(ele => ele[0]);
```

The real magic is happening behind GroupByOrder, which is an extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupByOrder<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, K> keySelector) where K : IComparable {
  var prevKey = keySelector(source.First());
  var captured = new List<T>();
  foreach (var curr in source) {
    if (keySelector(curr).CompareTo(prevKey) <= 0) {
      yield return captured;
      captured = new List<T>();
    }
    captured.Add(curr);
  }
  yield return captured;
}
```

(Disclaimer: idea stolen from Tomas Petricek)

Your sample data yields the following groups, which now just have to be parsed into your User object.

```
User:
  first_user_name
  first_user_phone
  first_user_fax
User:
  second_user_name
User:
  third_user_name
  third_user_phone
  third_user_fax
  third_user_address
User:
  last_user_name
  last_user_fax
```

Comment: hi fjdumont.. thanks for posting.. I'm still favouring dtb's answer as it is complete ie. takes a Message input and returns a list of Users. Also, your solution seems to break when non user data is present..ie original example only seems to work with 200/300/405 fields removed

Comment: @fjdumont.. do you have a link to Tomas Petricek's discussion of this?

Comment: I had to google it myself, but here it is: http://tomasp.net/blog/custom-linq-grouping.aspx

Comment: Thanks indeed.. jeees :-[ I feel bad now but I have decided to accept dtb's ans.. I actually found your var names more intuitive to follow but dtb's example is complete + correct.. whereas ur example is not complete + GroupByOrder always returns an initial empty group and is based on the keys having ascending numeric values ... both quick fixes but I had to nitpick so I could choose one over the other.. but much appreciated all the same.