# Linq self-join query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-4.0

I need some help with Linq self-join.

I have the following classs:

```
public class Owner
{
public string OwnerId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Area {get;set;}
public string City {get;set;}
public string Sex {get;set;}
public List<Dog> dog {get;set;}
}
```

And table....

```
ID OwnerId OwnerName TypeId TypeName   TypeValue        TypeCodeId
1     1     John       1     Area      United States       440
2     1     John       2     City      Los-Angeles         221
3     1     John       3     Sex       Female              122
4     2     Mary       1     Area      Mexico              321
4     2     Mary       2     City      Cancun              345
............................................................
```

I need to parse results of table1 into list of owners the fastest way possible. 
Note: Type can be null, but I still need to show that owner (So, I assume left join should work).

Here's What I do. (owners is a webservice class that contains table1 results)

```
public IEnumerable<Owner> GetOwners() { 
  return  (from owner in owners 
          join area in owners into owner_area
          from oa in owner_area.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join City in owners into owner_city
          from oc in owner_city.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join sex  in owners into owner_sex
          from os in owner_sex.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where oa.TypeId == 1 && oc.TypeId ==2 && os.TypeId ==3
          select new Owner() {OwnerId = owner.OwnerId, 
                              Name = owner.Name,
                              Area = oa.TypeValue,
                              City = oc.TypeValue,
                              Sex = os.TypeValue}).Distinct(); 
}
```

This query has several issues:

1. It returns multiple results and distinct does not work as expected
2. I've tried to use GroupBy but it says that cannot implicitly convert Owner into      `IEnumerable <int, Owner>`
3. It is super slow

How can I get distinct record with self join and improve performance?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Thank you guys for your ansewers, testing now, but I figured out that I forgot to supply one more thing. I've added a new column called TypeCodeId to the table layout(see above) 
User can filter values based on their selection. So, I have TypeCodeId + TypeValue dictionaries for Area, City and Sex. All of those parameters are optional (If the user didn't select any, I just show them all records.

So, Assume that the user has selected filter `Area: Unites States` and filter `City: Los Angeles`

them my query would look like this:

```
Select Projects where Area equals United States(440) and City equals Los Angeles(221)
```

If Only Area:Mexico was selected then my query would read something like this:

```
Select Projects where Area equals Mexico(321)
```

I'm not sure how to do optional where clauses with what you've provided in the examples.

Comment: Is *that* your actual table? Get thee to the normalization chamber.

Comment: Thank you. Not mine. I got it from the existing webservice. :)

Comment: Distantly related: [Replace for-switch loop with a Linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607629)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best performance if think this is the way to do it.

```
public IEnumerable<Owner> GetOwners(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> filter)
{
    var q = (from o in owners
            join f in filter on 
               new {o.TypeId, o.TypeCodeId} equals 
               new {TypeId = f.Item1, TypeCodeId = f.Item2}
            select o).ToList();

    var dic = q.ToDictionary (o => new {o.OwnerId, o.TypeId}, o => o.TypeValue);
    foreach (var o in q.Select(o => new { o.OwnerId, o.OwnerName }).Distinct())
    {
        var owner = new Owner()
        {
            OwnerId = o.OwnerId,
            Name = o.OwnerName
        };
        string lookup;
        if(dic.TryGetValue(new {o.OwnerId, TypeId = 1}, out lookup))
            owner.Area = lookup;
        if(dic.TryGetValue(new {o.OwnerId, TypeId = 2}, out lookup))
            owner.City = lookup;
        if(dic.TryGetValue(new {o.OwnerId, TypeId = 3}, out lookup))
            owner.Sex = lookup;

        yield return owner;
    }
}
```

To get even a little more performance you can write an `IEqualityComparer` class that only compares int OwnerId and send it into the `Distinct` function

Comment: Your solution works great and very fast. Can you please see my update?

Comment: I think a join on the input filer should do it (have not tested it) where `Item1 = TypeId` and `Item2 = TypeCodeId` in the `Tuple<int, int>`

Answer (score 3):

Since the table isn't normalized we need to get the distict users from the objects/table. This can be accomplished with:

```
owners.Select(o => new { o.OwnerId, o.OwnerName }).Distinct()
```

And then we need to join the "types" with two matching values, one for the ownerId and another for the specific type.

```
var ownerQuery =
    from o in owners.Select(o => new { o.OwnerId, o.OwnerName }).Distinct()

    join area in owners on new { o.OwnerId, TypeId = 1 } equals new { area.OwnerId, area.TypeId } into areas
    from area in areas.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join city in owners on new { o.OwnerId, TypeId = 2 } equals new { city.OwnerId, city.TypeId } into cities
    from city in cities.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join sex in owners on new { o.OwnerId, TypeId = 3 } equals new { sex.OwnerId, sex.TypeId } into sexes
    from sex in sexes.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new 
        { 
            owner = o,
            Area = (area != null) ? area.TypeValue : null, 
            City = (city != null) ? city.TypeValue : null, 
            Sex = (sex != null) ? sex.TypeValue : null, 
        };
```

You may need to change the projection in the above example.